# At what point is it too late to build Rod of Ages?

Tags: league-of-legends

I play a lot of AP champs, and most of them scale well with RoA. But sometimes I get so bossed in lane either by a camping jungler or because I just get straight out played. Sometimes it gets to like 20 minuets and I still haven't completed it. So I'm wondering what is the average point in the game where RoA is no longer worth completing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**RoA:**](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rod_of_Ages)

> Your champion gains 18 health, 20 mana, and 2 ability power every
>   minute. Bonuses cap at +180 Health, +200 Mana, and +20 Ability Power.
>   Unique: Upon leveling up, restores 250 health and 200 mana over 8
>   seconds.

If you check, you need 10min to get the RoA with his full power.

Take this in consideration in EVERY single game, some times a game will last for 1h (60min) others only 25min or even 20min.

- RoA is a item that you can get at early and mid game.
- You can get RoA at 40min if you see the game flow is slow and will
  last for at least more 15min

> ***Conclusion:*** Take it with 15min or more for the end of the match (You can estimate it after some time of game) Usually 25min is the
>   maximum available, so the game will end with 40min.

Answer (score 0):

Its never too late to build RoA, but if you get in late game you need to stacks its stats so will it be worth it. But it´s a tanky ap item.

Answer (score 0):

20 minutes is the standard, "too much time has passed" for it to be considered optimum.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after 20 minutes if you don't have it mostly finished, then the time to wait for the stat buffs isn't worth it.

Answer (score 0):

It's an item that gets stronger with time, so it's never too late if you feel you can hold on for that long.  Fortunately catalyst is still a great item to have in lane, and you can always make that into a banshee veil.